# Apt-get with no HTTP/FTP access

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb

Is it possible to install packages using `apt-get install` without having HTTP access? In other words, can apt-get install packages from a *small local repository*?

I know I can use `sudo dpkg -i deb_file` to install a package, but this will install only one package at a time and it will fail if the dependencies are not met. This will be a problem if I want to install a package that has many dependencies even if I already have all the required .deb files.

Comment: @Tshepang: I updated the title to include FTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common work-around is to put your `.deb` files into `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Then any `apt-get install` will look for the files in that cache first, and then try to download them if they are not there.

Alternatively, you can `dpkg -i *.deb` to install all packages in the current directory.

Comment: I remember I tried the second way using dpkg, and it did not work. I think because the packages are not installed in the required order! I still can try the first option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to install standard Debian packages you could use [apt-zip](http://wiki.debian.org/AptZip) that allows you download packages offline and transfer them onto the machine on some sort of removable media. I haven't really used it for a number of years but when I had a slow network connection at home it was a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-offline` or `apt-offline-gui`.
**Pre-requistes**: A friend's system with Internet connection. apt-offline installed in both your systems.

The Offline installation is achieved in 3 simple steps.

**Step 1**:
Generate a signature file on the Disconnected Debian box at home
`apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig`
The above command will generate all information required from apt about updating its database.

**Step 2**:
Download data based on the signature file generated earlier
`apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --threads 5`
The above command will download data as mentioned in the signature file. To speed up downloads (that can be from multiple apt repositories), in this example we spawn 5 download threads.
Once completed, you could just copy the data (an archive file, if you used the --bundle option) back to the removable medium and copy it back onto your offline host.

**Step 3**:
Once you're back upon the home Debian machine, you feed the data from the removable medium to apt-offline:
`apt-offline install /media/USB/apt-offline.zip`
This will update the APT database on your disconnected machine seamlessly.

Apt-offline can be even used in Windows systems. In my opinion, `apt-offline` is the best option for Offline installation.

[Source](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)